# Trying to create browser within a browser - using AJAX to browse a site without actually redirecting, but running into recursive problems. Help?

Tags: jquery, ajax, recursion, load

I'm trying to build a site that loads another site within it, but with custom css. To do this, I'm loading the page, disabling all attached css, and then firing the function below.

I want it to stop the browser from redirecting on click, read the href, and replace the content of a section with the same content from a new page. This function will then fire on the loaded content as well, allowing me to navigate within the section without actually being redirected.

```
function linkHijack() {
    $('a').click(function(event) {

      event.preventDefault();
      var link = $(this).attr("href");
      $('div#content').load(link+'div#content', linkHijack());

    });
}
```

It seems to be working correctly at first, but the function does not work on the newly loaded content. How do I get it to hijack the new links as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a .live() for older versions of jquery, .delegate() for mid versions and .on() for the newest versions.

This will ensure any new content returned by ajax has their events bubble up.

```
$('a').live("click", function(event) {

      event.preventDefault();
      var link = $(this).attr("href");
      $('div#content').load(link+'div#content', linkHijack());
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, even with using .on instead of .click, it still does not fire the hijacker once the new content has been loaded. What else could I be missing?

Comment: $(document).on("click", "a", function() {      event.preventDefault();
      var link = $(this).attr("href");
      $('div#content').load(link+'div#content', linkHijack());
 });

Comment: Ah! I found the problem - the page was also loading an older version of jquery in addition to 1.7.1 somewhere. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need event delegation. **[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7!**

Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead:

```
$('div#content').on('click', 'a', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var link = $(this).attr("href");
      $('div#content').load(link+'div#content');
});
```

This code 'listens' for clicks on `div#content` that 'come' from `a`.